# What is the difference between private and private[Class] declaration in scala?

Tags: scala

The class below compiles. How can I see the difference between those two scopes if there is any?

```
class C1 {
  private val p = 0
  private[C1] val pClass = 1

  def m1(other: C1) {
    println(other.p)
    println(other.pClass)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They are almost equivalent, and most definitely are equivalent in all common use cases.

*But*, there actually is a very tiny semantic difference between the two:

- `private` restricts access to the enclosing class `C1` and its companion object, but the definition **is not inherited by subclasses** and cannot override definitions in parent classes.
- `private[C1]` also restricts access to `C1` and its companion object, but that member **is inherited and can be overridden by a child class**, as long as that class has access to it (if it is enclosed by `C1`).

Here is an example:

```
class A {
  private[A] val i = 1

  def display() { println(i) }

  class B extends A {
    override private[A] val i = 2
  }
}

val a = new A
a.display // 1
val b = new a.B
b.display // 2 !!
```

`B` can override `i` because it has access to it, and it has access to it because it is an inner class of `A`. This would not compile if `i` were `private` (nothing to override), and if `override` were removed, then `display` would return `1` and not `2`.

So basically, unless you have inner classes extending the class itself, `private[C1]` will behave exactly like `private`.

---

**Note** also that because of the above, they are not implemented the same at the bytecode level:

- `private val p` creates:

  - a private field `p`
  - and a private accessor method `p()`
- but `private[C1] val pClass` creates:

  - a private field `C1$$pClass`
  - and a *public* accessor method `C1$$pClass()`